# Ubuntu desktop shows odd layout

Tags: desktop-environments, visual-artifacts

When I logged into Ubuntu my desktop looked like this image below and I can't do anything with it. What can I do?

[image: UbuntuDesktop]

It's inside VirtualBox, so the results of

ubuntu-drivers devices are:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0 ==
manual_install: True
model    : VirtualBox Guest Service
modalias : pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc08sc80i00
vendor   : InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
driver   : virtualbox-guest-dkms - distro non-free
driver   : virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe - distro non-free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0 ==
model    : VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
modalias : pci:v000080EEd0000BEEFsv00000000sd00000000bc03sc00i00
vendor   : InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
driver   : virtualbox-guest-x11 - distro non-free
```

Comment: @karel ubuntu-drivers devices does not seem to show any insight why it stopped working. Desktop worked fine and then it suddenly got messed up.

Comment: @karel No, it works fine in my other VirtualMachines.